# Jenkins - Build Pipeline plugins icon not showing properly

Tags: build-pipeline

I am installing **build pipeline plugins** but icon showing broken. Same error in docker, manual installation of jenkins and using tomcat9.

Kindly help me to solve this error.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

I install jenkins using docker, tomcat and manual[image]